# Install error when adding Identity Server features to WSO2 ESB 4.5.1 on WSO2 Carbon 4.0.3

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I have been trying to add identity server features to a vanilla esb 4.5.1 install specifically to enable openid and oath2 sso. attempts to add the features fail with missing dependencies. for example

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found. Software being installed: Identity Provider Feature 4.0.3 (org.wso2.carbon.identity.provider.feature.group 4.0.3) Missing requirement: Identity Core Feature 4.0.3 (org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.feature.group 4.0.3) requires 'org.wso2.carbon.core.feature.group [4.0.3,4.1.0)' but it could not be found Cannot satisfy dependency: From: Identity Provider Feature 4.0.3 (org.wso2.carbon.identity.provider.feature.group 4.0.3) To: org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.feature.group [4.0.3,4.1.0)

I am using the http://dist.wso2.org/p2/carbon/releases/4.0.3 P2 repository is this a problem with the repository or have i simply missed the point and am trying something that can not be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIR, ESB 4.5.1 was released on top of the Carbon Kernel Version 4.0.2. And the latest identity features in the feature repository that you are pointing to, were released on top of the Carbon Kernel version 4.0.3. Therefore you might not be able to install those unless the p2 repository carries the 4.0.2 version of identity features in it.

Comment: AFAICS 4.0.2 does not contain Identity Server so I presume I need to wait for next ESB